# How to set readonly property in BoundFiled Cell in true?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, boundfield

I do it like this:

```
 if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text != null && e.Row.Cells[3].Text != "&nbsp;" 
          && e.Row.Cells[3].Text != "")
 {
     e.Row.Cells[3].Attributes.Add("readonly", "true");
 }
```

But it doesn't work. I need to set readonly property in true when cell is empty or contains " ".

Answer (score 0):

There is no `direct way` to set `Gridview column` to `readonly`.
But You can set the `controls to readonly` that are in that column in `RowDataBound` event of your Gridivew. e.g.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit || e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("ControlID");
        txt.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For bound fields you can assume Controls(0) is the control you want.

Therefore this works:

```
    Protected Sub DropDownListNoVariation_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim sourceGridViewRow As GridViewRow
    Dim sourceDropDown As DropDownList
    Dim TargetTextBox As TextBox

    sourceGridViewRow = sender.Parent.Parent
    sourceDropDown = sender
    If sourceDropDown.Text = "True" Then
        TargetTextBox = sourceGridViewRow.Cells(4).Controls(0)
        TargetTextBox.ReadOnly = True
        TargetTextBox = sourceGridViewRow.Cells(5).Controls(0)
        TargetTextBox.ReadOnly = True
    Else
        TargetTextBox = sourceGridViewRow.Cells(4).Controls(0)
        TargetTextBox.ReadOnly = False
        TargetTextBox = sourceGridViewRow.Cells(5).Controls(0)
        TargetTextBox.ReadOnly = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Would this work?

```
if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text != null && e.Row.Cells[3].Text != "&nbsp;" && e.Row.Cells[3].Text != "")
 {
     e.Row.Cells[3].ReadOnly = true;
 }
```

It sure seems as though the `BoundField` has a [`ReadOnly` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.readonly.aspx). But I am not sure now if the `e.Row.Cells[3]` is of `BoundField` type. Maybe you might have to cast it to `BoundField`

Comment: Yes it has. But how could i change it. e.Row.Cell[3].ReadOnly not correct.